# Use Gif image in Surface view?

Tags: android, surfaceview, gif

I am developing an android application , in which i am using a gif images with the following code

```
private static byte[] streamToBytes(InputStream is) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    try {
        while ((len = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    }
    return os.toByteArray();
}
```

// In constructor of the class

```
is = this.context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.fondo_juego_nexus);

            if (DECODE_STREAM) {
                  System.out.println("in if DECODE_STREAM");
                mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
            } 

            else {
                byte[] array = streamToBytes(is);
                System.out.println("in else  DECODE_STREAM");
                mMovie = Movie.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);
           }



// In On Draw 

  long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        if (mMovieStart == 0) {   // first time
            mMovieStart = now;
        }
        if (mMovie != null) {
            System.out.println("in if (mMovie != null)  " + mMovie.duration());
            int dur = mMovie.duration();
            if (dur == 0) 
            {
                dur = 1000;
                System.out.println("in if movie if");
            }
            System.out.println("duration is  "+ dur);
            int relTime = (int)((now - mMovieStart) % dur);
            mMovie.setTime(relTime);
            System.out.println("in if displaying syd");
            mMovie.draw(canvas,120,100);

        }
```

and by ontouch i exit from activity like

```
else if(_y<=60 &&  _x<=60)
         {


             sp.play(mySound1, volume, volume, 0, 0, 1);
             sp.release();
            playr.stop();
             tme.cancel();
             act.finish();

}
```

Bu when i exit activity with above method and go back to previous activity ,
and come again to the activity where i am using gif image it does not appear , on device galaxy s2  ,  2.3.3 but on an emulator of same size of 2.2 it is fine

is there any problem with this approach or what way i can use to display a gif image

what should i do to remove this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for my problem , i do not know how good it is ,
but it worked for me  earlier i was using this code in constructor

```
 if (DECODE_STREAM) {
                mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
            } else {
                byte[] array = streamToBytes(is);
                mMovie = Movie.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);
            }   

        }
```

It was workign fine first time, but i think in second time it was running out of memory due to
too much of garbage collector which was running implicitly 
and my image initialization was also running again and again which was the cause of the 
bad performance of the game ,and 
what i did was that i just added 
the garbage collector manually with

```
System.gc();
```

and initialized all images after this and  also
placed the following code

```
if (DECODE_STREAM) {
                mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
            } else {
                byte[] array = streamToBytes(is);
                mMovie = Movie.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);
            }   

        }
```

after this 
which avoided the implicit running of garbage collector

and now the gif image is working fine